# Animating cape (Blender 2.79)

Tags: cloth-simulation

I am trying to do an animation that involves a cape. I decided I would try to use the cloth simulation but I ran into an issue. My normal method for animating with a character involves the character to be in one spot in one frame, and then the next frame they are in a different location. I decided to test this with the cloth simulation to see how it would react. Unfortunately, the jump makes the cape go crazy.

[image]

Here's a download for the file: http://pasteall.org/blend/index.php?id=52662

What I want is for the cape to stay roughly in the same position before the jump. What would be the best way to achieve this, or is there another way I could animate the cape?

Comment: Relevant: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/86393/why-is-my-cloth-simulation-jagged

Answer (score 0):

Holy smoke! You need to slow down the jump a lot! If you make the cape a more solid material, and slow down the jump a lot (Maybe to 5 frames). Also, what would make a better simulation would be to make the cape facing the opposite direction of the jump. AKA, if you jump -5 on the x axis, set the cape to be pointing towards the positive side.

Comment: Is there any way to reset the cloth during your animation? Like having two different starting points.

Comment: You only need to re-bake the cloth to reset it with different settings.

Comment: But could I start a new simulation later in the animation?

Comment: I'm not entirely sure why you would want to do that, but yes, you can, and it's tricky.